# Getting floats to work correctly in CSS

Tags: html, css

I thought I understood floats, but seems I don't.

I've got a div (#service-list) which I've floated left and I've added another div (#social) straight after, floating left too.

What's happening is the 2nd div after is being pushed down to a new line despite there being enough room to fit the div.

```
#service-list{
width: 660px;
border-right: 1px solid #808080;
border-bottom: 1px solid #808080;
border-left: 1px solid #808080;
float: left;
padding: 15px 0 20px 15px;
margin: 0 0 0 25px;
clear: both;
}
#social{
width: 200px;
float: right;
clear: left;
border: #666 solid 1px;
}
```

Here's the url: http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/101d/tim/index.html

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: There's a `<div class="clearfix">` between those two in the HTML. Also, `#social` has `clear: left`, which means it **should** appear under any other elements that are `float: left`. Get rid of those and the social media box will be stuck under the element above.

Comment: Also: why not use a grid framework? Seems like it'd be a good fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

And `clear: left;` in `#social`

```css
#social{
    width: 200px;
    float: right; /* You should better use float: left */
    border: #666 solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `clear` in a lot of spots before you want float elements to occur which prevents them from floating properly.  I was able to get this to work by doing the following:

1. move `#social` before `#services-list` in the DOM
2. Remove `clear: both` from `#services-list` (otherwise it won't float)

Answer (score 0):

You have an clearfix between service-list and social with `clear:both` - so theres naturally not floating - clear:left in service-list is also wrong..